# Shared Methods Between Selenium And SpecFlow

Tags: c#, design-patterns, selenium, bdd, specflow

I have a test project that holds all the Selenium scenarios that I want to test and I want to add a SpecFlow project to this solution that obviously will use some of the WebDriver methods.
I don't want to duplicate my code but the SpecFlow is not working well with the Selenium (for example Selenium is using the [TestInitialize] attribute which is not allowed in SpecFlow).
What is the best way to combine the two?

I want to do the same steps as in "SomeTestMethod" but with SpecFlow.

This is an example of the project:

```
public class SeleniumBaseTest : BaseTest
{
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void Initialize(TestContext testContext)
    {
    }

    Public SomeMethod()
    {
    }
}
[TestClass]
public class SeleniumFeature : SeleniumBaseTest 
{
   [TestInitialize]
   public void SeleInitialize()
   {
   }

   [TestMethod]
   public void SomeTestMethod()
    {            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since SpecFlow steps are really just public methods on a class that inherits from `System.Object`, just instantiate the step definition class and call the public methods from your Selenium test.

**DataSteps.cs**

```
[Binding]
public class DataSteps
{
    [Given("Something exists in the database")]
    public void GivenSomethingExistsInTheDatabase()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In your Selenium test class:

```
[TestClass]
public class SeleniumFeature : SeleniumBaseTest 
{
    private DataSteps dataSteps;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SeleInitialize()
    {
        dataSteps = new DataSteps();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeTestMethod()
    {
        dataSteps.GivenSomethingExistsInTheDatabase();
    }
}
```

The only real pain is when you need to use a `TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table` object as a parameter to a step definition. To figure out that syntax look at the Designer-generated source for one of the `.feature` files that uses the Gherkin table syntax, e.g.

```
Scenario: Testing something important
    Given a Foo exists with the following attributes:
        | Field | Name  |
        | Name  | Foo   |
        | Fruit | Apple |
```

If it helps, you can keep the step definitions in their own assembly.

Comment: This is a possible solution, but my Selenium projects use some complex patterns so it is not helping me.
I need to maintain the current design and add to it the SpecFlow.
But it is a good solution, Thanks.

Comment: I understand. You might be better off with two different projects. As you create a scenario in SpecFlow, remove the redundant coverage in your Selenium project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attributes aka hooks like:

[BeforeTestRun]
[AfterTestRun]

[BeforeFeature]
[AfterFeature]

[BeforeScenario] or [Before]
[AfterScenario] or [After]

[BeforeScenarioBlock]
[AfterScenarioBlock]

[BeforeStep]
[AfterStep]

For detailed information about hooks, go [here](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks)